# HuggingFace BPE Trainer Error - Training Tokenizer

Tags: python, nlp, google-colaboratory, huggingface-tokenizers

I am trying to train a ByteLevelBPETokenizer using an iterable instead of from files. There must be something I am doing wrong when I instantiate the trainer, but I can't tell what it is. When I try to train the tokenizer with my dataset (clothing data from Kaggle) + the BpeTrainer, I get an error.

```
**TypeError**: 'tokenizers.trainers.BpeTrainer' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

I am using Colab

Step 1: Install tokenizers & download the Kaggle data

```
!pip install tokenizers

# Download clothing data from Kaggle
# https://www.kaggle.com/nicapotato/womens-ecommerce-clothing-reviews/version/1?select=Womens+Clothing+E-Commerce+Reviews.csv
```

Step 2: Upload the file

```
# use colab file upload
from google.colab import files
uploaded = files.upload()
```

Step 3: Clean the data (remove floats) & run trainer

```
import io
import pandas as pd  

# convert the csv to a dataframe so it can be parsed
data = io.BytesIO(uploaded['clothing_dataset.csv']) 
df = pd.read_csv(data)

# convert the review text to a list so it can be passed as iterable to tokenizer
clothing_data = df['Review Text'].to_list()

# Remove float values from the data
clean_data =  []    
for item in clothing_data:
  if type(item) != float:
    clean_data.append(item)   


from tokenizers import ByteLevelBPETokenizer
from tokenizers.processors import BertProcessing
from tokenizers import trainers, pre_tokenizers
from tokenizers.trainers import BpeTrainer
from pathlib import Path


# Initialize a tokenizer
tokenizer = ByteLevelBPETokenizer(lowercase=True)

# Intantiate BpeTrainer
trainer = BpeTrainer(
    vocab_size=20000,
    min_frequence = 2,
    show_progress=True,
    special_tokens=["<s>","<pad>","</s>","<unk>","<mask>"],)

# Train the tokenizer
tokenizer.train_from_iterator(clean_data, trainer)
```

Error - I can see that the trainer is a BpeTrainer Type.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-103-7738a7becb0e> in <module>()
     34 
     35 # Train the tokenizer
---> 36 tokenizer.train_from_iterator(clean_data, trainer)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tokenizers/implementations/byte_level_bpe.py in train_from_iterator(self, iterator, vocab_size, min_frequency, show_progress, special_tokens)
    119             show_progress=show_progress,
    120             special_tokens=special_tokens,
--> 121             initial_alphabet=pre_tokenizers.ByteLevel.alphabet(),
    122         )
    123         self._tokenizer.train_from_iterator(iterator, trainer=trainer)

TypeError: 'tokenizers.trainers.BpeTrainer' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Interesting Note: If I set the input trainer=trainer I get this

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-104-64737f948e6d> in <module>()
     34 
     35 # Train the tokenizer
---> 36 tokenizer.train_from_iterator(clean_data, trainer=trainer)

TypeError: train_from_iterator() got an unexpected keyword argument 'trainer'
```

Answer (score 2):

I haven't used `train_from_iterator` before but looking at the [HF docs](https://huggingface.co/docs/tokenizers/python/latest/tutorials/python/training_from_memory.html) it seems you should use a generator function. So something like:

```py
def clothing_generator():
  for item in clothing_data:
    if type(item) != float:
      yield item
```

Followed by:

```py
tokenizer.train_from_iterator(clothing_generator(), trainer)
```

Might help?

Comment: Thanks, James. I had thought the same, but other instantiations didn't seem to require that. I did try it though and now I get this TypeError: 'tokenizers.trainers.BpeTrainer' object cannot be interpreted as an integer not sure what is up.

Comment: @scarpacci that's very odd, I'll give this a go some time - you've probably already checked but when you filter out `!= float` rows, you do still have data left?

Comment: Yeah I do have data. Good thought. Thanks for the help. Has to be something stupid. I just was trying to avoid having to write out files for smaller datasets.

Comment: I am having the same error as OP. Did you find a solution to this problem finally?

Comment: the link is dead.